# python json to csv， How to read a file in chunks or line by line

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

My code，

```
import json
import pandas as pd

file_path = "F:\\2\\1.json"
with open(file_path, 'r',encoding='utf-8') as fh:
    file_data = fh.readlines()

all_data = []
for data in file_data:
    data = data.strip()
    if data:
        all_data.append(json.loads(data))
df = pd.json_normalize(all_data)

df.to_csv('F:\\2\\1.csv',encoding='utf-8',index=False)
```

When reading a large file, it will prompt "MemoryError"，How to modify my code？

my json file

```
{"_index":"core-bvd-dmc","_type":"_doc","_id":"e22762d5c4b81fbcad62b5c1d77226ec","_score":1,"_source":{"a_id":"P305906272","a_id_type":"Contact ID","a_name":"Mr Chuanzong Chen","a_name_normal":"MR CHUANZONG CHEN","a_job_title":"Executive director and general manager","relationship":"Currently works for (Executive director and general manager)","b_id":"CN9390051924","b_id_type":"BVD ID","b_name":"Yantai haofeng trade co., ltd.","b_name_normal":"YANTAI HAOFENG TRADE CO","b_country_code":"CN","b_country":"China","b_in_compliance_db":false,"b_nationality":"CN","b_street_address":"Bei da jie 53hao 1609shi; Zhi fu qu","b_city":"Yantai","b_postcode":"264000","b_region":"East China|Shandong","b_phone":"+86 18354522200","b_email":"18354522200@163.com","b_latitude":37.511873,"b_longitude":121.396883,"b_geo_accuracy":"Community","b_national_ids":{"Unified social credit code":["91370602073035263P"],"Trade register number":["370602200112047"],"NOC":["073035263"]},"dates":{"date_of_birth":null},"file_name":"/media/hedwig/iforce/data/BvD/s3-transfer/SuperTable_v3_json/dmc/part-00020-7b09c546-2adc-413e-9e68-18b300e205cf-c000.json","b_geo_point":{"lat":37.511873,"lon":121.396883}}}
{"_index":"core-bvd-dmc","_type":"_doc","_id":"97871f8842398794e380a748f5b82ea5","_score":1,"_source":{"a_id":"P305888975","a_id_type":"Contact ID","a_name":"Mr Hengchao Jiang","a_name_normal":"MR HENGCHAO JIANG","a_job_title":"Legal representative","relationship":"Currently works for (Legal representative)","b_id":"CN9390053357","b_id_type":"BVD ID","b_name":"Yantai ji hong educate request information co., ltd.","b_name_normal":"YANTAI JI HONG EDUCATE REQUEST INFORMATION CO","b_country_code":"CN","b_country":"China","b_in_compliance_db":false,"b_nationality":"CN","b_street_address":"Ying chun da jie 131hao nei 1hao; Lai shan qu","b_city":"Yantai","b_postcode":"264000","b_region":"East China|Shandong","b_phone":"+86 18694982900","b_email":"xyw_700@163.com","b_latitude":37.511873,"b_longitude":121.396883,"b_geo_accuracy":"Community","b_national_ids":{"NOC":["597807789"],"Trade register number":["370613200023836"],"Unified social credit code":["913706135978077898"]},"dates":{"date_of_birth":null},"file_name":"/media/hedwig/iforce/data/BvD/s3-transfer/SuperTable_v3_json/dmc/part-00020-7b09c546-2adc-413e-9e68-18b300e205cf-c000.json","b_geo_point":{"lat":37.511873,"lon":121.396883}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json (r'F:\2\1.json')
df.to_csv (r'F:\2\1.csv', index = None)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work for my json file

Comment: can you add your json file? @jeriteri

Comment: yes i just added it

Answer (score 0):

To avoid running out of memory, you could append the output CSV for each input line of JSON. This should then work with any size of file. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

add_header = True

with open('1.json') as f_json:
    for line in f_json:
        line = line.strip()
        
        if line:
            df = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(line))
            df.to_csv('1.csv', index=None, mode='a', header=add_header)
            add_header = False
```

---

Speed can probably be improved by reading and processing a group of lines before writing the output. Here it keeps processing until a threshold is reached:

```
import pandas as pd

add_header = True
df = pd.DataFrame()

with open('1.json') as f_json:
    for line in f_json:
        line = line.strip()
        
        if line:
            df_line = pd.read_json(line)
            df = pd.concat([df, df_line])
            
            if df.size > 10000:
                df.to_csv('1.csv', index=None, mode='a', header=add_header)
                add_header = False
                df = df.DataFrame()

if df.size:
    df.to_csv('1.csv', index=None, mode='a', header=add_header)
```

Note: This also just uses `read_json()` instead of `json.loads()`

Comment: Why do you do the ```if line``` part?

Comment: The code can work, but it runs very slowly, 10M is written in 1 minute, my JSON file is very large, it has dozens of BG,

Comment: @Wayow, this is in keeping with the OPs code which is probably dealing with blank lines in the source file

Comment: Your speed could probably be improved by reading and concatenating say 1000 lines at a time before writing to the CSV